# Failed to pass value from one activity from another (only null value passed)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried to pass variable from one activity to another. In the main activity I managed to call back the values using Toast message.

MainActivity.java

```
search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View w) {
                subreg = spinner_subregion.getSelectedItem().toString();
                reg = spinner_region.getSelectedItem().toString();
                pettype = spinner_pet.getSelectedItem().toString();
                petnumber = spinner_num.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity, Result.class);
                intent.putExtra("subregion", subreg);
                intent.putExtra("region", reg);
                intent.putExtra("petnum", petnumber);
                intent.putExtra("pet", pettype);
                startActivity(intent);

         
}
}
```

However, when I passed the value to Result.java, it only returns null. I tried searching for solutions and still does not work for me. Anyone knows how can I pass the data?

Result.java

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras!=null){
            subreg = extras.getString("subreg");
            reg = extras.getString("reg");
            pettype = extras.getString("pettype");
            petnumber = extras.getString("petnumber");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
MainActivity.java

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("subregion", subreg);
 intent.putExtra("region", reg);
 intent.putExtra("petnum", petnumber);
 intent.putExtra("pet", pettype);
startActivity(myIntent)
```

Result.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view);
    
        Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent ==null){
........
.......
}else{
       

    
        String subregion= intent.getStringExtra("subregion");
        String region= intent.getStringExtra("region");
        String petnum= intent.getStringExtra("petnum");
        String pet= intent.getStringExtra("pet");
}
    }
```

Comment: It works, except i didn't change the variable name..

Answer (score 0):

This is my code after changing it.

MainActivity.java

```
        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View w) {
                subreg = spinner_subregion.getSelectedItem().toString();
                reg = spinner_region.getSelectedItem().toString();
                pettype = spinner_pet.getSelectedItem().toString();
                petnumber = spinner_num.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(Pet_sitting.this, Pet_sitting_result.class);
                intent.putExtra("subreg", subreg);
                intent.putExtra("reg", reg);
                intent.putExtra("pettype", pettype);
                intent.putExtra("petnumber", petnumber);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Result.java

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent == null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Null value passed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            subreg= intent.getStringExtra("subreg");
            reg= intent.getStringExtra("reg");
            pettype = intent.getStringExtra("pettype");
            petnumber = intent.getStringExtra("petnumber");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),subreg + " " + reg + " " + pettype + " " + petnumber,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you are using a Spinner in your code.
So it's Obvious a spinner can give you only one value at a time after Spinning the wheel...
you need to set the Code inside in null value Exception...
like...if it's null don't pass empty value inside intent
maybe it's worked...if it's then reply

> MainActivity.java

```
if(subreg != null){
   reg = spinner_region.getSelectedItem().toString();
   intent.putExtra("reg", reg);
 }
 startActivity(intent);
```

> Rsult.java

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
 if (intent == null){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Null value passed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }else{
    reg= intent.getStringExtra("reg");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),reg.toString,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```